# How to detect installed Free Pascal on Windows computer?

Tags: registry, freepascal

I want to detect installed Free Pascal (about version, install directory...) on my windows computer. Using c#, how to find FPC information on windows registry?

Comment: You write code, typically.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why do you want to do this. After all there are many different ways to get FPC onto a machine

Comment: Try `C:\>where fpc` to get the program location and `C:\>fpc -iW -iD` to get FPC version and date for example (using command line). If it works then u can simply use it in the C# app by calling `cmd` and catching its output.

Comment: PS: If you interesting in FPC then you should to remember that it is cross-platform and it try to avoid using OS-specific features like "windows registry". This does not mean that you can not use the Registry in your FPC programs, but using it your programs will not cross-platform.

Comment: @abelisto if you want to read some information that is held in the registry how would you go about doing that without reading the registry?

Comment: please don't downvote my question! :(

Comment: @Sent If you improved the question it would be voted up.

Comment: @Abelisto: FWIW, on my Windows 7 Ultimate, `where.exe` was only usable after I copied it to a directory in the path (I have a special `C:\Tools` directory for that). It works as expected.

Comment: If you solved the problem then provide the answer how do you done it. @DavidHeffernan It was informative to discuss with you, but I delete my comments not related to the Q. Let's keep SO clean! ;o)

Comment: @Abelisto I agree, let's keep it clean, you left the first one, me too

Answer (score 2):

Free Pascal is open source, the innoscript file for the installer is [available](http://svn.freepascal.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/install/fpc.ist?view=markup&root=fpcbuild)

From this you can see there are two groups of registry keys:

1. The extensions are registered to the textmode IDE, if installed
2. the directory is added to the PATH

Both in differing ways depending on if setup is run as admin or not, according to the result of the functions IsHKLM(Not)Writeable

Versions delivered with Lazarus are installed by a different installer, and so a different script though.

And then there are people that build by hand. FPC does not need some system configuration to function, so if the packaging system (setup, msi etc) doesn't do it, the only thing to do is either search the disk for fpc.exe or try probably locations like c:\fpc\bin\i386-win32 and c:\lazarus\fpc\bin\i386-win32

Answer (score 1):

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Management;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(IsProgramInstalled("Free Pascal"));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static bool IsProgramInstalled(string programDisplayName)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Checking install status of: {0}", programDisplayName));
            foreach (var item in Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall").GetSubKeyNames())
            {

                object programName = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\" + item).GetValue("DisplayName");

                string n = (string)programName;
                if (n!= null && n.Contains(programDisplayName))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Install status: INSTALLED");
                    Console.WriteLine(programName);
                    Console.WriteLine(Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\" + item).GetValue("InstallLocation"));
                    return true;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Install status: NOT INSTALLED");
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you remember that the program can be accessible simply by `PATH` and have no any "traces" in the registry?

Comment: how to use PATH? My code above run correctly?

Comment: The code above runs correctly, to find things in the Registry for programs installed by a Windows installer. But, as has been said, FPC is not always installed by a Windows installer, and may not have an entry in the Registry. It does not even have to have an entry in the PATH environment variable, since that can even be done delayed, i.e. only when FPC is called, e.g. in a batch file. How come? Because some people do not use an installer, and install everything manually, the way they like it.